# How to get length of audio file without playing it in Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to display the length of audio files in my Flutter application.  I've used both the flutter_sound and audioplayers plugins but I'm not sure how to get the length of the audio file without playing it and getting the duration (which I want to display the length of each audio file in a list so users know how long it is before playing).  I haven't been able to find anywhere online that shows how to get the audio file length in dart except from using the duration of the playing audio file in one of those plugins. Anyone know how to get audio file length's in dart?

Answer (score 10):

This is a late answer but incase if you are still wondering how to do that, There is a audio library [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio)

```
final player = AudioPlayer();
var duration = await player.setUrl('file.mp3');
```

Works on both android and IOS, supports both local files and download urls.

Comment: I actually came here because just_audio is giving me the wrong duration on iOS.

Comment: this returns Future<Duration?> object. how can i get duration ?

Comment: @DimuthDeZoysa await it and while it loads just display a loader or simply show 0.00.

Answer (score 4):

Late answer but maybe it still helps someone.

You can try [ffmpeg_kit_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/ffmpeg_kit_flutter) like so:

```
import 'package:ffmpeg_kit_flutter_full_gpl/ffprobe_kit.dart';

Future<double> getFileDuration(String mediaPath) async {
  final mediaInfoSession = await FFprobeKit.getMediaInformation(mediaPath);
  final mediaInfo = mediaInfoSession.getMediaInformation()!;

  // the given duration is in fractional seconds
  final duration = double.parse(mediaInfo.getDuration()!);
  print('Duration: $duration');
  return duration;
}
```

Of course ffmpeg is a very large libary for such a small task but it advoids playing the audio file which I did not like either.

Comment: Unfortunately, [flutter_ffmpeg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg) has been discontinued.

Comment: It has just moved as said in the repo https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit

Comment: I approved Michas edit with complete confidence that a stranger on the internet did provided correct code. I haven't used ffmpeg_kit_flutter myself so far

Comment: @Micha, is it possible to use this with an audio asset?

Answer (score 4):

If you still want to use [AudioPlayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) and [AudioCache](https://github.com/luanpotter/audioplayers/blob/master/doc/audio_cache.md) then load the file before actually playing it. Otherwise you will get an error when implementing the division of your [Slider](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Slider-class.html).

Use AudioCache to pre-load the file, this would return a future of the file. Chain it with
then block and use the passed file which would have path in it. Set the url on the audio player and return it. Chain this another then block and in that return the future from getDuration call. Now use this in your future builder with a spinning loader when the snapshot is null and your music player when snapshot has a value.

Consider this example:

```
Future<int> loadFile() {
return audioCache.loadFile(widget.fileName)
    .then((value) {
      print(value);
      cachedFilePath = value.path;
      return audioPlayer.setUrl(value.path, isLocal: true);
    })
    .then((value) => audioPlayer.getDuration());
}
```

I called this function in the initState to avoid multiple calls to the future and stored the future in a Future variable.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    print("init");
    super.initState();

    audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();

    audioCache.init();

    audioPlayer.onDurationChanged.listen((d) => setState(() => _duration = d));

    audioPlayer.onAudioPositionChanged.listen((p) => setState(() => _position = p));

    audioPlayer.onPlayerCompletion.listen((event) {
      setState(() {
        _position = Duration(seconds: 0);
        issongplaying = false;
      });
    });

    _loadFile = loadFile();
  }
```

Next I used the `_loadFile` variable in my future builder. And in the future builder I also added a loader.

```
return FutureBuilder(
  future: _loadFile,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.data == null)
      return // Implement your loading spinning widget here
    else
      return // Implement your widget here
```

Comment: audioCache.loadFile has been removed from the package do you have any idea whcih is replaced with this?

Answer (score 3):

The `media_info` package is in development and attempts to solve this problem.

https://pub.dev/packages/media_info

The documentation is found in the code at the moment. In the `MediaInfo()` class you can get the following information

Example

```dart
final MediaInfo _mediaInfo = MediaInfo();
...
   final Map<String, dynamic> info = await _mediaInfo.getMediaInfo("your/media/file");
   final yourPropertyValue = info["yourPropertyKey"];
...
```

Replace `yourPropertyKey`  with one of the keys that are found [in the source code here](https://github.com/ened/flutter_plugin_media_info/blob/8dd90b908a2259e8eb32fc1fe82f0d3f7d5fe2ac/lib/media_info.dart) and I listed them below for each file type.

| Images | Videos | Audio |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mimeType | mimeType | mimeType |
| width | width |  |
| height | height |  |
|  | frameRate |  |
|  | durationMs | durationMs |
|  | numTracks |  |
|  |  | bitrate |

Comment: how to get durationMs from this ?

Comment: @DimuthDeZoysa Since info is a map, use await to get the value from the future and then use `info["durationMs"]` to access the value. It will only be present for videos and audio files. I changed my answer to be more clear as well.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```dart
    // We need to play the file in order to get its duration.
    _player = await AudioCache().play(filePath);

    _player.onDurationChanged.listen((Duration duration) {
      // Now that we have the duration, stop the player.
      _player.stop();
      _durationMs = duration.inMilliseconds;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First add "just_audio:" in pubspec.yaml and import it in the required screen file.
Now you can adjust the code according to your need:

```
final player = AudioPlayer();

void getDuration(String path) async {
    var duration = await player.setFilePath(path);
    return duration;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your Duration initally starts at zero, but only gets the total Duration of the song when played then you need to use the `audioPlayer.setSource()` :)

Answer (score -1):

By This Method you will get Duration in this formate **Max duration: 0:06:12.715000**

```
  AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();

  audioPlayer.onDurationChanged.listen((Duration d) {
    print('Max duration: $d');
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

I am using the below code to get an audio file duration. [audioplayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers)

First call

```
AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();   
audioPlayer.setUrl(audioFilePath, isLocal: true);
```

it will trigger the audio player onDurationChanged listener function from there we will get the max duration of and audio file without playing.

```
audioPlayer.onDurationChanged.listen((Duration d) {
  print('max duration: ${d.inSeconds}');

});
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this library [audioplayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers),

Fetch duration event like this

> This event returns the duration of the file when it's available (it might take a while because it's being downloaded or buffered).

```
  player.onDurationChanged.listen((Duration d) {
    print('Max duration: $d');
    setState(() => duration = d);
  });
```

[image]

Comment: That's the plugin I'm using, but the duration state of the player doesn't change to get the duration until the player is playing (which I want to have a list of players and show the duration of each of their audio files). Do I have to start and quickly stop each file to get it to load for the duration to change?